# Прокинуть в pipes параметр из запроса

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Есть эндпоинт, в котором нужно валидировать параметры. Скажем:

```
@Get('/:id')
getFriend(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) userId) {
    return `Get friend: ${userId}`;
}
```

Здесь я указываю, что нужно проверить, что это число.

```
import {PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ParseIntPipe implements PipeTransform<string, number> {
    transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): number {
        const val = parseInt(value, 10);
        if (isNaN(val)) { 
            // как-то нужно прокинуть параметр local и локализовать ошибку
            throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Но в параметрах также может передаваться `local` клиента, на основе которого данные формируются. К примеру, локализуется ошибка. Как этот параметр, если он есть, передать в pipes?

Comment: а что за параметр local? То есть где в данном коде должен/может определяться этот параметр?

Comment: @Grundy он либо в body, либо в query.

Comment: он описывается как параметр той же функции getFriend: `getFriend(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) userId, @param('local') local) {`? Или как-то по другому к нему доступ осуществляется?

Comment: @Grundy ну вот мне этот `local` нужно прокинуть в `ParseIntPipe` валидатор для `userId` (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту, локалька нужна только для локализации ошибок. Следовательно, можно использовать [Exception Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters). В большинстве случае у нас выбрасывается кастомная ошибка, поэтому написал такой фильтр:

```
@Catch(NomeraException)
export class NomeraExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    private errorsService: ErrorsService;

    constructor(tt: ErrorsService) {
        this.errorsService = tt;
    }

    catch(exception: NomeraException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        const headers = request.headers;
        const status = exception.getStatus();
        const local = headers.local ? headers.local : config.general.DefaultLocale;
        const code = exception.getCode();
        const message = this.errorsService.getErrorMessage(code, local);

        response
            .status(status)
            .json({
                error: {
                    code: exception.getCode(),
                    message: message
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Ну и в основном модуле его подключаем:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
const errorsService = app.get(ErrorsService);
app.useGlobalFilters(new NomeraExceptionFilter(errorsService));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipes не предназначены для подобного, и я не вижу нормального способа прокинуть в него локаль. Лучшее решение на мой взгляд - это выкидывать исключение из Pipe-а как есть, а переводить по локали их на [Interceptor-е](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)